# optimal message box size with wordwrap 2

Tags: c, user-interface

Having a fixed size characters and a text which should wrap the whole words into next line, what would the optimal algorithm to calculate the fitting centered square which should be closest to the square take least of space and look good for user?

Screen is defined as this

```
#define max_width 1024
#define max_height 768
#define char_width 10
#define char_height 16
```

Function to calculate generated wrapped text size in characters

```
void calculate_wrapped_text_size( const char *text, int box_width_in_px, int &width_in_chars, &height_in_chars )
{
 ...
}
```

So given an input as
Line1 text longtext longertext anytext`\n`Line2 <... ...> it will calculate the wrapped text fitting the given width

```
void find_optimal_size( const char *text, int &optimal_width_in_px, int &optimal_height_in_px )
{
 ...
}
```

Is there any standard way to calculate what would be the most optimal size in width and height so it will look best for the user? I thought going the path of finding least area box, and then iterating to the size of least difference on sides?

Answer (score 0):

The "least area box" you thought about would certainly be just a single line - which is not what you want.

First, check if you need to write the line-wrap algorithm yourself at all, because most GUI toolkits whether native or cross-platform (can) do this for you.

If you need to do this yourself do it like this: calculate the maximum line-width you want to allow. Based on the width of your display-window or based on the layout of the other widgets in that window.

Then for each line: write until a word would reach over that maximum width, that word is the first one that needs the next line.

There are details you have to think about: First of all whether your letters are all of the same width (which would make the word-width calculation much easier) and which characters you consider word-boundaries (space, tab, "-").

There are corner cases to consider, e.g. what to do if the window is so narrow that a specific word will not fit even if it is the first word of the line: The algo above would just keep adding more and more lines; you have to add a special case to the algorithm that a word may not be word-wrapped if it is the first word of the line, it instead has to be character-wrapped ie just write as many characters into the line as possible and the remaining in the next line.

Comment: But I have stated, that I would search the most 'rectangular' box after I locate/sort all possible combinations by the area. Yes and the characters are of the fixed width and height

Comment: @Ulterior it is almost always rectangular. do you mean "square"?

Comment: iterating through 0->screen width, 0->screen height would produce a lot of combinations